# Conditional Join if Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to join two tables together based on a three-column key stack. The problem is sometimes one of the key columns is translated and mapped differently in another table. I will attempt to example my issue using code:

```
select t1.TQ
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t1.comp_cd = t2.comp_cd and t1.plcy_frm = t2.plcy_frm 
                            and t1.val_cd = t2.val_cd
```

The columns "comp_cd" and "plcy_frm" are fine, however the problem is with val_cd. Sometimes the val_cd in table2 does not map correctly to table1 and must go through a third table, table3. Table3 structure is below:

```
Val_Cd        Mapped_Val_Cd
A123         A564
```

So -> I need to join on `Mapped_Val_Cd` value when it exists in `Table3`, but join on `Val_Cd` from `Table2` when `Val_Cd` does not exist in `Table3`.

I hope this makes sense - I have tried Case when exists syntax but cannot get that to work.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help clarify what you want to do.

Comment: I'd be more than happy to provide sample data and desired results! Do you know how i can format tables here? I am new to Stack OverFlow.

Comment: You can format data the same way as code.  The simplest way is to pre-pend each line with four spaces.  Another way is to highlight the code and click on the `{}` icon just above the input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicates in `table3`, you can `left join` it in and then choose the value that you want in the `on` clause:

```
select t1.TQ
from table1 t1 left join
     table3 t3
     on t1.val_cd = t3.val_cd
     table2 t2
     on t1.comp_cd = t2.comp_cd and
        t1.plcy_frm = t2.plcy_frm and
        t1.val_cd = coalesce(t3.Mapped_Val_Cd, t2.val_cd);
```

Comment: Actually - this code did exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for the quick and accurate solution!!